# How to change last characters in string in php

Tags: php, string, replace

I have the question how change/replace last characters in string in php
I have three surname:

```
Nowak
Kowalski
Nowacki
```

Now my code work for Kowalski and Nowacki. When I change gender for surname Kowalski and Nowacki it work, but this work also on Nowak.
I want change last characters only when string ends on

```
ski
cki
```

on

```
ska
cka
```

When last characters is another I don't want change/replace anything.
My actual code:

```
<?php
$string = 'Nowak';
$temp = rtrim($string, "ki ka");
$sex = 'm';
if($sex == 'k')
{
    $temp.='ka';
}
else
{
    $temp.='ki';
}
?>

<h1>Before change: <?=$string;?></h1>
<br>
<h1>gender: <?=$sex;?></h1>
<br>
<h1>After change: <?=$temp;?></h1>
```

Comment: `preg_replace('/([sc])ki$/', "$1ka", $string);`

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/rtrim   the 2nd arg is a CHARACTER MASK, not a list of strings to strip. `"ki ka"` is executed as if it was "kia[space]", and strips any/all of those characters from the end of the string, regardless of the order they appear in.

Comment: I find this question to be Unclear.  Is the name suffix determined by `$sex` or should it be unconditionally toggled? Please [edit] to express a [mcve] -- ideally with 3-5 input strings and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$name = 'Kowalski';

// Get the last three characters
$last_three = substr($name, -3);

// Based on last three characters, substr() and append as needed
switch($last_three)
{
    case 'ski':
        $name = substr($name, 0, -3).'ska';
        break;
    case 'cki':
        $name = substr($name, 0, -3).'cka';
        break;
}

echo $name;
```